# Rails dynamically generated fields_for are not picked up as inputs by form_tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm trying to create multiple objects in one form. Not a parent-child relationship thing, the objects are all the same.

When the code looks like the below, it works just fine.

```
<%= form_tag create_object_path, id: "create-object-form" do %>
  <%= render "admins/object_fields" %>
  <!-- repeat render any number of times -->
<% end %>

# where the render looks like this:
<%= fields_for "objects[]" do |f| %>
  <tr class="new-object">
    <td><%= f.text_field :name %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

One way to test, is that in the console, `$("#create-object-form").serializeArray()` correctly returns the number of input fields based on how many `object_fields` have been rendered.

However, when the render is dynamically called, then none of the dynamically added `fields_for` show up in the submission. And calling `$("#create-object-form").serializeArray()` only returns 2 fields, the `utf8` and `authenticity_token` that are auto-generated by the `form_tag`. Code that's no tworking

```
<%= form_tag create_object_path, id: "create-object-form" do %>
  <!-- render called by JS -->
<% end %>

<button id="add-object">Add</button>

$("#add-object").click(function() {
  $.ajax({})...
  // correctly fetches and renders the partial on the page in the correct spot.
})

# where the render STILL looks like this, no change:
<%= fields_for "objects[]" do |f| %>
  <tr class="new-object">
    <td><%= f.text_field :name %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: In Rack you can't reliably pass an array of hashes through array parameters. Take this example: `objects[][foo]="bar"&objects[][id]="1"&objects[][foo]="baz"&objects[][id]="2"`. Rack has no way of knowing what hash each value belongs to. Instead you need to pass a hash of hashes:  `objects[0][foo]="bar"&objects[0][id]="1"&objects[1][foo]="baz"&objects[1][id]="2"`.

Comment: If you pass an array or any enumerable to fields_for  it will actually loop through the collection and properly set this up.

Comment: @max i'm a little confused, your first comment suggests that the issue is in passing an array over a hash (even though my program can pass an array just fine, with multiple objects, as long as they are not dynamically rendered), but then your second comment suggests an array is fine? i'm not entirely sure what you're suggesting as the solution, sorry!

Comment: The first comment is about how rack interprets form data parameters, when you pass `fields_for "objects[]"` you are going to construct parameters that Rack won't be able to deal with.

Comment: My proposed solution's to the problem is to not do this. If you are using Ajax and adding the records one by one you can just have one form for each record instead - its far less complex and hacky.

Comment: ok got it thanks for the feedback. though i will say, unless i have misunderstood severely, the array method is how rails conventionally passes child objects when you have a form with nested attributes? like, the generated naming convention looks like `child_object_attributes[][id]`. and i haven't had a problem with it before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is interesting. I don't understand why, and didn't do a ton of experimentation on it, welcome anyone to further add.

The question was missing some context. The inputs were in rows in a table, so the code actually looked like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>...content...</thead>
  <%= form_tag form_path, id: "form" do %>
    <tbody>
      <!-- either pre-rendered or dynamically generated trs with input fields -->
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
          <button id="submit">Submit</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

The `form_tag` wrapped around the `tbody` which contained the `trs` with `input` fields. In that version of the code, only pre-rendered inputs were picked up upon submission or by `.serializeArray()`, as the question mentioned.

However, if I move the `form_tag` to be outside the `table` tag, then it works; i.e., dynamically added `trs` with `input` fields are successfully picked up upon submission or by `.serializeArray()`.

Again I don't know why, couldn't find any documentation suggesting this is expected behavior, so feel free to let me know. Thanks!

Working code:

```
<%= form_tag form_path, id: "form" do %>
  <table>
    <thead>...content...</thead>
    <tbody>
      <!-- either pre-rendered or dynamically generated trs with input fields -->
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
          <button id="submit">Submit</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
<% end %>
```